# Query key not equal to

Tags: c#, couchdb

I have a model as follows:

```
class Page{
   int statuscode;
}
```

Then I have this view,

```
function (doc, meta) {
   if(doc.statusCode){
     emit(doc.statusCode, 1);
   }
}
```

I want to query this index to get the status codes that is not 200 and 300.

I am using c#.

I can query this view with a `key(200)` this gives me the reduce for it. But i want to find reduce that is not 200 and 300. ie: i want to get 400, 404, 500 etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying "Not In" in Couchbase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890297/querying-not-in-in-couchbase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'not' functionality when querying views. But depending on your situation you may try one of two things:

**Key Range**
If all of the keys you DO want are within an unbroken range, then you can specify a startkey and endkey to capture those statuscodes.

**Key List**
If you know all the keys you DO want and it is a relatively small list, you can specify a list of keys.

Documentation on querying Views: http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-querying.html